# How to implement watermark text in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a view which contains some posters with respective download buttons as shown below :[view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur4Oo.jpg)

The download when clicked is currently going to a white blank page as shown below :

[error page after clicking download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKgUa.png)

There is an error displayed in the above page.

```
function poster_download($filename = NULL) {

 $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
  $config['source_image'] = 'http://localhost/3girps.org/3gcommune/eventmanagement/images/posters/Poster-1.jpg';
  $config['wm_text'] = 'Codeigniter @2020 - Tutorial and Example.com';
  $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
  //$config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
  $config['new_image'] = 'http://localhost/3girps.org/3gcommune/eventmanagement/application/uploads/watermark.jpg';
  $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
  $config['width']         = '700';
  $config['wm_font_size'] = '32';
  $config['wm_font_color'] = '#4f1a10';
  $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
  $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
  $config['wm_padding'] = '5';
  $config['wm_margin'] = '20';
  $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
  $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
  //phpinfo();
                   
  $this->image_lib->watermark();

  echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
```

}

I have enabled gd2 in `php.in` as shown below :

```
  extension=gd2
```

But still the error is showing "The path to the image is not correct.Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image."

view page :

```
 <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url()?>eventmanagement/images/posters/Poster-1.jpg" style="height: 100%;width: 72%;" alt="" />
                                     <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>eventmanagement/poster_download/Poster-1.jpg" class="readon radius mt-4">Download</a>
```

When I am clicking on the download button, I wanted to watermark the text on the image and also wanted to download the watermarked image.Can anyone help me out in this ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsyPA.png)

Comment: Does [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) show GD is installed and OK? How did you install GD?

Comment: yes..i have updated the above post. I have included the screenshot.

Comment: Path must be absolute/relative server path not url

Comment: means ? didnt understand ?

Comment: $config['source_image'] = 'http://localhost/3girps.org/3gcommune/eventmanagement/images/posters/Poster-1.jpg';   to $config['source_image'] = 'images/posters/Poster-1.jpg';    and $config['new_image'] = 'http://localhost/3girps.org/3gcommune/eventmanagement/application/uploads/watermark.jpg'; to $config['new_image'] = 'uploads/watermark.jpg';

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#preferences *The path must be a relative or absolute server path, not a URL*